# Android background color transition from left to right

Tags: java, android, xml

I was wondering if there is a way to animate the background from a relativelayout , so that the color changes from e.g blue to yellow, from left to right in about 1 second. (This animation should be triggered onclick).
Appreciate any help,
ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can use [AnimationDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), the most basic way it's to have three color : blue, a gradient blue-yellow and yellow :

In **res/drawable** create a gradient.xml file (left to right):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#FFFF00"
        android:startColor="#0000FF" />
</shape>
```

Then in the same folder create a animalion-list.xml file :

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#0000FF" android:duration="333"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" android:duration="333"/>

    <item android:drawable="#FFFF00" android:duration="333"/>
</animation-list>
```

Apply the animation-list as background to your relative layout :

```
<RelativeLayout:
    android:...
    android:...
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation-list"
    android:... >

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your code :

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground();

mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            animationDrawable.start();
    }
});
```

I'm not sur that this code give you that your exactly expected but with some imagination, you should get that you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Drawable `gradient_2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/deep_purple_500"
        android:endColor="@color/blue_700"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

and usage inside `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

You can change agle of colorfull 0 , 45 , 90 , 180

```
android:angle="0"
```

You can also add `centerColor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#D8EDFD"
        android:endColor="#D8EDFD "
        android:startColor="#F6F9FF " />
</shape>
```

[image: background would be like]